# How do I catch 'connection refused' exception in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to know how I can catch a 'connection refused' exception in Java when I am using socket. (which would happen when server is down or not responding.)

Below is how I have implemented so far.

```
    try {
        sockfd = new Socket(host.getHostName(),heart_port);
        sockfd.setReuseAddress(true);
        BufferedReader message = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader ( sockfd.getInputStream() ) );
        message.close();
        sockfd.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: May be you will get it in second catch block that is IOException.

Comment: You are catching the io exception with connection refused already. Can you add some detail to you question?

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException` should be thrown. As it inherits from `IOException` you already catch it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html

Comment: I forgot to mention I specifically wanted to catch connection refused exception

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add *ConnectException* before *IOException*

```
catch (ConnectException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple I missed haha!